# Server/Client game optimization: Byte or int? (Java)

Tags: memory, optimization, int, byte

I am making a multiplayer game and I have one simple question:
  **Would using a byte instead of an int make ANY difference in ram usage and bandwidth?**

I just want to know if it makes any difference at all, big or small, when transferring data from server to client or storing data in server ram. Since I am unsure how many people will actually play the game, I would like to design it assuming there are millions of players even though the chances of that are small, just a precaution.

I would only use byte for values that are meant to be limited anyway, such as player's direction (only 4 values, north, east, south, west) so 256 as a max number is more than enough.

Comment: It a classic case of premature optimization. The answer will depends on the chose platform and programming language, however, it is very likely your bottle neck will be somewhere else with millions of players.

Comment: Alright thanks, makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Java an `int` is 32 bits and a `byte` is 8 bits, so yes using `byte`s would theoretically save resources.

But, as Knuth wrote (and for good reason), ["premature optimization is the root of all evil"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil).  Code first, measure performance second, optimize third iff necessary.

Comment: Hmm.. Alright, I'll do that, I guess there's no point in doing that now, maybe when the time comes, if it even comes. Thanks for your answer.